# How works precision Float of numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

Hello guys I'm working on `javascript` file about **astronomical calculations** so I need more precisions.
I have a lot operations for each line and I want like result more precision (also ten or twenty decimal after comma).

In JavaScript if I do not declare number of decimal (for example using `.ToFixed(n)`), how many **positions** after the comma, the language consider during the calculation?

For example:

```
var a= 1.123456789*3.5; // result 3.9320987615
var b= a/0.321;
var c= b*a;

// c => 48.16635722800571
```

It will be the result?
**Like using all decimal after comma for each variables of javascript does approximations ?**

Why in other questions users suggests to use `decimal.js` or other libraries?

I'm sorry if my question seems stupid but for me is important.
I hope you can help me.

Sorry for my english !

Comment: [Number.toPrecision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision)

Comment: But i should to use that method for each variable, for each data, each line? Or only for the result ?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript uses IEEE-754 double-precision, that means it only calculates numbers to around 15 decimal digits of precision, any more than that gets cut off. If you need more precision you have to use `decimal.js` or another similar library. Other questions recommend `decimal.js` or other libraries is because it is easy to put into your program and can provide as much precision as you want.

The reason it isn't implemented in the computer by default is that it takes a lot more effort for the computer to calculate to 20 digits over 15 digits because the computer is built to compute only to 15 decimal digits. If you want to read more on it I would recommend reading [Arbitrary Precision Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) on Wikipedia.

Comment: In other words: the type with approx. 15 digits precision is a hardware supported type. Anything larger cannot be done with available hardware support so is not only more difficult (must be done completely in software) but also a lot slower.

Answer (score -1):

Simply because the toFixed() method converts a number into a string, keeping a specified number of decimals. So, the returned value will be a string not a number.